# Norm function in pracma package overwrites class Norm in distr

Tags: r

The pracma package has a function Norm, but the distr package has a class Norm [Norm-class {distr}   Class "Norm" Description - The normal distribution ...]

- how can I use both packages without having one overwrite the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to use the functions you want from `pracma` without loading the package by using `pracma::foo` to reference the `foo` function (for example).